# is it possible to send a media file in JsonResponse in ajax?

Tags: json, ajax

I wanted to know if is it possible to get media file such as (.mp3) as Json Response, if it's not then how music sites play songs even without refreshing surely they don't load all the songs at first get request.

Comment: You add the link to your mp3 in the json response, and then load it with javascript. `{"music": "http://yoursite.com/musics/my-song.mp3", "name": "My song"}`

Comment: You can send a blob